# Having issues with jquery ui datepicker and IE

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui

This works perfectly in Firefox but doesnt work in ie i get the following error "Line: 640
Error: Object doesn't support this property or method"

Here is my code

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="calendardatedob" CssClass="calendardatedob" runat="server" AccessKey="n" TabIndex="4" MaxLength="40" /><span
                    class="req">*</span> e.g dd/mm/yyyy
```

Here is my jquery

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#ctl00_PageContent_calendardatedob").datepicker();       
     });
```

im referencing these

```
<script src="../../assets/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../assets/js/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: ive changed to selector to .calendardatedob instead but still get error

Comment: Is it saying line 640 in your webpage, or the javascript file?  If it's in the page, view source and make sure that this is indeed the error, could be something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether this is your error or not, but you can use **[Control.ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(VS.71).aspx)** to get an element inside a naming container.

```
$("#<%= calendardatedob.ClientID %>").datepicker();
```

If this is also not working then check whether all the js files are loaded or not, using a DOM inspector.

Comment: ive changed to selector to .calendardatedob instead but still get error

Comment: Try `$(".calendardatedob").length` and check whether it is `> 0`